# "Nicer Version" of Bayes' Theorem?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

My Textbook says this for Bayes' Theorem

For any two events $A$ and $B$ with nonzero probabilities

$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A)P(B\mid A)}{P(B)}$$

This is the standard formula for Bayes' theorem that I know and am familiar with, but the textbook says that the following is another alternative "nicer" formula of Bayes' Theorem:

If $P(B) \neq 0 $ and $0 < P(A) < 1$ then,

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A)P(B\mid A)}{P(A)P(B\mid A) + P(A^C)P(B\mid A^C)}$$

I see what they did, they just broke $P(B)$ into $$P(A\cap B) + P(A^C \cap B) = P(A)P(B\mid A)+P(A^C)P(B\mid A^C)$$
and substituted the denominator with this in the 2nd formula.

My question is, why is this version of the formula "nicer"? Is it in the case you don't know what $P(B)$ is? But know $P(A)$ and $P(B\mid A)$ (which naturally gives you $P(A^C)$ and $P(B\mid A^C)$)?

Comment: What is your textbook? Why does it say it is "nicer"?

Comment: It is introduction to probability by Mark Daniel Ward and Ellen Gundlach pg 63

Comment: The version you use really depends on the application. For calculating predictive values of tests in the medical context, I use the second version, so even though it looks less compact, it's more useful in that context. I have no idea why it might be called "nicer" though, as that's highly imprecise and subjective.

Comment: Yes, it's in case you don't know what $\mathbb{P}(B)$ is. The usual formulation of Bayes' theorem is quite deceptive; in practice often the only way to calculate $\mathbb{P}(B)$ is as the denominator in the second form of Bayes' theorem you give.

Comment: This ain't exactly what you are asking for, but I believe the following video might be of general interest to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZGCoVF3YvM&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown. It in particular discusses various "versions" of Bayes' theorem and their pros and cons.

Comment: I suspect it is "nice" for the  case you start not knowing $P(B)$; alternatively it gives you the "normalizing constant".  As a further point, $P(B \mid A)$ does not give you $P(B \mid A^c)$ though it does give you $P(B^c \mid A)$

Comment: To me, a nicer version of Bayes theorem would handle cases where $P(B)=0$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox to see why it may be important.